# how to make routes work in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to learn angular and I have simple out of the box app. I have a main page and it works fine but when I try to go to any other page, it redirects me back to main page. I am suspecting that this is what causing it, but I am not sure how to fix it.
my app.js has this

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

I have my main.js and about.js controller.
here is my main.html

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="text-muted">angular</h3>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Shipit</h1>
  <p class="lead">
    <img src="images/yeoman.png" alt="I'm Yeoman"><br>
    Always a pleasure scaffolding your apps.
  </p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#">Splendid!<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></p>
</div>

<div class="row marketing">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <ul>

            <!-- Here we use the AngularJS directive: ng-repeat to loop through our awesomeThings
            and print them out as list items using the {{}} bindings -->
            <div ng-repeat="thing in awesomeThings">{{thing}}</div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="footer">
  <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
</div>
```

and here are my controllers

about.js controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma',
        'php'
    ];
  });
```

and main.js controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma',
        'php'
    ];
  });
```

I want the links to be routed to the correct place in about etc...I want to do it angular way.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you only have one route defined:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

so if the user goes to /foo it will fall to the otherwise which will put you to main.

Add another route:

```
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html', //possibly uses a different template
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var app = angular.module('App', [ 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html', controller: 'DashboardCtrl' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
});
```